# WPF binding to ViewModel property from the DataTemplate Style

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding, datatemplate

I am trying to bind `ForeGround` color of all `TextBlock` items to a `ViewModel` property. The `TextBlock` elements locate under a `Grid` that itself is defined under `DataTemplate`. This whole code is defined under a `UserControl`.

I am trying to use `RelativeSource` binding to find the `UserControl`'s `DataContext` and get the property I need.

XAML:

```
<my:MapControl>
    <my:MapControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="SomeTemplate">
                <Grid>
                     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                          <RowDefinition />
                          <RowDefinition />
                     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                     <Grid.Style>
                         <Style TargetType="Grid">
                              <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.TextColor}" />
                         </Style>
                     </Grid.Style>
                     <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" />
                     <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </my:MapControl.Resources>
</my:MapControl>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MapViewModel
{
    public virtual string TextColor
    {
        get { return _textColor; }
        set
        {
            _textColor = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("TextColor");
        }
    }
    private string _textColor = "Black";
}
```

The above binding doesn't work. If I change the Value binding to a hard-coded value, like "Red" for example, the `Foreground` color on those `TextBlocks` are showing correctly.

How to get the binding to work with this setup?

Comment: Did you remove it when you pasted code of forgot to implement INPC interface: `MapViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged`. If this is just simplification then are you sure `MapViewModel` is `DataContext` of your `UserControl`?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the get of TextColor, property, is it called ? Watch the output window  (Ctrl+Alt+O) for any error message related to DataBinding. Check the assignment of you DataContext as suggests dkozl. Regards

Answer (score 0):

### Analysis

It seems the root cause — binding to an instance of the `string` type instead of an instance of the `Brush` type.

### Some of the possible solutions:

1. Change the type of the `TextColor` property of the `MapViewModel` class to from the `string` type to the `SolidColorBrush` type and update the implementation of the `MapViewModel` class appropriately.
2. Create custom implementation of the `IValueConverter` interface which takes the `string` as the input and outputs an instance of the `SolidColorBrush` type.

Answer (score 0):

What version of .NET are you using? Works fine with 4.5 but IIRC it didn't with earlier versions and you had to declare a solidcolorbrush explicitly:

```
<Style TargetType="Grid">
    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.TextColor}" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Whatever you do don't create a brush or any other UI resources in your viewmodel, it's a violation of MVVM.